# How do I change the frequency of a tone in java?

Tags: java, audio

I am writing a programm and i want it to play a frequency. But i dont know where in my code i have to change something.

```
 try
    {
        byte[] buf = new byte[ 1 ];;
        AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat( (float )44100, 8, 1, true, false );
        SourceDataLine sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine( af );
        sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine( af );
        sdl.open( af );
        sdl.start();
        for( int i = 0; i < 1000 * (float )44100 / 1000; i++ ) {
           double angle = i / ( (float )44100 / 440 ) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
           buf[ 0 ] = (byte )( Math.sin( angle ) * 100 );
           sdl.write( buf, 0, 1 );
        }
        sdl.drain();
        sdl.stop();
        sdl.close();
        }
    catch (Exception x1)
    {

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following line:

```
double angle = i / ( (float )44100 / 440 ) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
```

Play with the number 440. This number should be your frequency in hz. I know this through process of elimination and 440hz is the audio realm's "Hello, World".

Theoretical range of hearing is 20hz to 22000hz. (22khz)

In most cases, with normal hearing and speakers you're looking at 65hz-16000hz

Some other things you're seeing:

44100 - your sample rate

1000 - pretty sure this is just ms in a sec. So 44100/1000 converts from samples/sec to samples/ms

Math.sin - creating a y-value based on time (what sample you're on, essentially.) with a sin function

If you want to better understand this in a short amount of time; look up definitions for sample rate and bit depth.

Also, as always, rtfm...  Look at the docs and check out what the arguments are for the parameters you're passing in.

```
 AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat( (float )44100, 8, 1, true, false );
```

44100 is sample rate, but to me 8,1,True,False could mean anything. (8 might be bit depth. 16 bit is more common, 1 could mean mono...).

Comment back if checking this stuff out brings up more audio questions.

-Cheers